# Custom math function in panda dataframe with two columns

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, math

I would like to get this custum function for a panda dataframe to work.

It is a simple function with two inputs

- wordCount
- imageCount

and supposed to calculate the reading time of a text in a panda dataframe.

c = ImageCount
x = WordCount

(5.717938 + (12.03401 - 5.717938)/(1 + (c /3.579499)^4.092419))* c) + x * 0.0037736111111111113

I tried it in a couple of ways, but could not get it to work properly.

```py
def readingT(df, y="imageCount", x="wordCount"):
    readingTimeImage = (5.717938 + (12.03401 - 5.717938)/(1 + (c/3.579499)^4.092419))* c
    readingTimeWords = 0.0037736111111111113 * x
    return readingTimeImage + readingTimeWords


def readingT2(c="imageCount", w="wordCount"):
    return ((5.717938 + (12.03401 - 5.717938)/(1 + (c/3.579499)^4.092419))* c + 0.0037736111111111113 * w)

readingT2.apply(readingT, c="imageCount", w="wordCount")

#Try next 

def readingT3(x, y):
    (((5.717938 + (12.03401 - 5.717938)/(1 + ( x /3.579499)**4.092419)) * x) + 0.0037736111111111113 * y)

readingT3.apply(lambda x: rule(x["imageCount"], x["wordCount"]), axis =  1)
```

Every single one of them gives throws out an error.

Cheers in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(c, x):
    return (5.717938 + (12.03401 - 5.717938)/(1 + (c /3.579499)^4.092419))* c) + x * 0.0037736111111111113
df['reading_time'] = df.apply(lambda x: f(x.imageCount, x.wordCount), axis=1)
```

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question.